# How to propagate project name from gradle build script into Idea project name using gradle's Idea plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm not sure if this is more Gradle or Intellij Idea question. In projet I'm importing to Idea using gradle import(import from Gradle external model in Idea) my build.gradle contains, besides other things, following:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    project {
        // When ext.(extra property) is not used, gradle complains about 
        // deprecated dynamic property, but only here, not when setting 
        // module name.
        ext.name = 'SimpleStoreClient'
    }
    module {
        name = 'SimpleStoreClient'
    }
}
```

When project import is finished, I open module settings in Idea, module name is set to one from gradle build script, but project name is just rootdir name. I tried few alternatives of setting project name, but no has propagate the name into Idea. 
I thing I just miss some property of Idea plugin, but I cant find what is it.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is setting the root projects name in settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = "Your alternative project name"
```

This will set the project name in project settings of idea and in the gradle tasks view to "Your alternative project name".

The project name that is displayed in the projects in Project View can't be influenced as far as I know.

Comment: Works exactly as you described, project name(in project settings, JetGradle etc.) is changed. Thanks!